# No validator can be found for String field

Tags: java, spring, string, spring-boot, spring-validator

I have a custom interface:

```
@Target({ FIELD })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = { MyCustomValidator.class })
@Documented
public @interface ValidData {

    String message() default EMPTY;

    Class<?>[] groups() default { };

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { };

}
```

and I have a class with a field that has this validator attached:

```
public class RecoverData {

    @ValidData(groups = AfterDefaultGroup.class)
    private String data;
```

`MyCustomValidator` class has the following method:

```
public class MyCustomValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidData, RecoverData> {

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(RecoverData recoverData, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        //my custom logic regarding recoverData.getData()
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now when I try to run it, I'm getting the following error:

> No validator could be found for constraint 'com.myPackage.ValidData' validating type 'java.lang.String'. Check configuration for 'data'

What could I do in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have *applied* your custom validator for a `String` *field* and not a `RecoverData` type - so your custom validator should actually be:

```
public class MyCustomValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidData, String> {

  @Override
  public boolean isValid(String data, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    //my custom logic regarding recoverData.getData()
    return true;
  }

}
```